# updating data from different URL using wget

Tags: wget

What's the best way of updating data files from a website that has moved on to a new domain, with changes in their folder structure.

The old URL for example is `http://folder.old-domain.com` while the new URL is `http://new-domain.com/directory1/directory2`. My data is stored locally in  ~/Data_Backup/folder.old-domain.com folder.

Data was originally downloaded using:

```
$ wget -S -t 0 -c --mirror –w 2 –k http://folder.old-domain.com
```

I was thinking of using mv to rename the old folder to follow the new URL pattern, but is there a better way of doing this?

Will this work? I'm not particular with the directory structure. What's important is to update the contents of the target folder (and its sub-folders.)

```
$ wget -S -t 0 -c -m –w 2 –k -N -np -P ~/Data_Backup/folder.old-domain.com http://new-domain.com/directory/directory
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I need to add the following options:
-nH --cut-dirs=2

and now it works.